# Help with Apache .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, nginx

Trying to convert my .htaccess file to **[NGINX](http://www.nginx.net)** notation.

I've read the online help guides but am still struggling.

Would anyone mind helping. My .htaccess is:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks  

# Enable ETag
FileETag none                       

# Set expiration header
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault A2592000
Header append Cache-Control "public"

# Compress some text file types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/json

# Deactivate compression for buggy browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Set header information for proxies
Header append Vary User-Agent

########################################################
# Rewrite Rules
########################################################

RewriteEngine on

# Require SSL (HTTPS) on the signup page
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/signup/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Redirect /signup/plan or /signup/plan/ ->  /signup/index.php?account_type=plan
RewriteRule ^signup/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1 [NC,L]

# Redirect /home/123 or /home/123/ ->  home.php?home_id=123
RewriteRule ^home/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?home_id=$1 [NC,L]

# Redirect /homes/ in case someone made a typo when it should have been /home/
RewriteRule ^homes/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?home_id=$1 [NC,L] 

###########################################################
# Error Handling
###########################################################

#ErrorDocument 400 /
#ErrorDocument 401 /
#ErrorDocument 403 /
#ErrorDocument 404 /
#ErrorDocument 500 /


#################################################
# Default Settings
#################################################

# hide apache server signaute on apache generated pages (e.g. 404)
ServerSignature Off
```

**UPDATE:**

For the GZIP compression, this appears to work. But I still haven't figured out how to my my HTTP Rewrites rules yet.

```
 gzip             on;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types       text/plain application/xml;
  gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried replacing my htaccess rewrite rules with the following NGINX rules but this doesn't appear to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
# Redirect /signup/planname or /signup/planname/ ->  /signup/index.php?account_type=planname
rewrite  ^signup/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1  last;

# Redirect /home/123 or /home/123/ ->  home.php?home_id=123
rewrite  ^home/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?home_id=$1  last;

# Redirect /homes/ in case someone made a typo when it should have been /home/
rewrite  ^homes/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?home_id=$1  last;
```

**UPDATE 3**

Per the comments below, I now have the following NGINX config but am still having problems

```
# gzip
gzip             on;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types       text/plain application/xml;
gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";


# Require SSL (HTTPS) on the signup page
# ====== THIS DOESN'T WORK AND BREAKS NGINX
# I obviously change "example.com" to be my actual domain
if (location /signup/) {
   rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}


# Redirect /signup/planname or /signup/planname/ ->  /signup/index.php?account_type=planname
rewrite  ^signup/([A-Za-z] +)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1  last;

# Redirect /home/123 or /home/123/ ->  home.php?home_id=123
# Also, Redirect /homes/ in case someone made a typo when it should have been /home/
rewrite  ^/homes?/([0-9]+)/?$  /home.php?home_id=$1?  last;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule), your rules (not conds) should be *like* this:

A:

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/signup/?
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
```

N (see [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/179377) for more info) :

```
if (location /signup) {
   rewrite ^ https://pma.clinicacgm.0$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

---

A:

```
RewriteRule ^home/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?home_id=$1
RewriteRule ^homes/([0-9]+)/?$ home.php?home_id=$1
```

N:

```
 rewrite  ^/homes?/([0-9]+)/?$  /home.php?home_id=$1?  last;
```

Comment: Thanks Eir. Question though, I only want #'s (digits) allows in the last rule. Looks like you made the rule to allow for any kind of character when you use "(.*)", how do I only make it #'s?

Comment: sorry, I've just copied from wiki.. There should be `([0-9]+)` or `([0-9]+)?` (I have no server where to test them hardly )

Comment: As such, any idea then why my UPDATE 2 isn't working since that's exactly what I did

Comment: but I don't know if there will be a trailing "/" or not. What my Apache config does is regardless if the trailing "/" is there, rewrite to home.php?home_id=$1.  How do I do that then?

Comment: from documentation: *If in the line of replacement arguments are indicated, then the rest of the request arguments are appended to them. To avoid having them appended, place a question mark as the last character*

Comment: Also, I just ran **if (location /signup) {rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;}** and it broke. So that code doesn't work

Comment: Eir, exactly. "place a question mark as the last character" - you told me to REMOVE the "?" mark. I'm confused, what should I do b/c you're telling me two different things

Comment: I've told about remove /? in RE, not in the replacement. misunderstanding

Comment: I updated my original post with UPDATE 3 but am still getting errors

Comment: It appears **rewrite  ^signup/([A-Za-z] +)/?$ /signup/index.php?account_type=$1  last;** isn't working